# JS RegEx: strings to JSON object

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to convert this:

```
-[firstLink](https://webapp.com/topic/ab75ca14-dc7c-4c3f-9115-7b1b94f88ff6)
--[secondLink](https://webapp.com/source/d93f154c-fb1f-4967-a70d-7d120cacfb05)
-[thirdLink](https://webapp.com/topic/31b85921-c4af-48e5-81ae-7ce45f55df81)
```

into this:

```
const obj = [{
    name: 'firstLink',
    type: 'topic',
    id: 'ab75ca14-dc7c-4c3f-9115-7b1b94f88ff6',
    spacing: 1, // single "-"
}, {
    name: 'secondLink',
    type: 'source',
    id: 'd93f154c-fb1f-4967-a70d-7d120cacfb05',
    spacing: 2, // two "-"
}, {
    name: 'thirdLink',
    type: 'topic',
    id: '31b85921-c4af-48e5-81ae-7ce45f55df81',
    spacing: 1,
}]
```

Here what i'm trying now:

```
const items = text.split('\n');
const re = /(-+)\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^)"]+)\)/
const arrays = items.map(function (item) {
    return item.split(re);
})
```

for some reason, `arrays` contains bunch of empty strings (`""`) at the start and end of each `item`.
1. So, first question, is how to get rid of it?
2. Is there alternative to [this regex tester](https://regex101.com/), which actually shows such issues? This one doesn't show empty strings in results and, probably, some other issues.

Next, i'll do this:

```
const result = arrays.map(function (singleArray) {
    if (!singleArray[1]) return null
    const spacing = singleArray[1].length;
    const name = singleArray[2]
    const typeRe = /(source|topic)/;
    const uuidRe = /([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})/;
    const type = typeRe.exec(singleArray[3])[1]
    const id = uuidRe.exec(singleArray[3])[1]
    return {
        name, type, id, spacing,
    }
})
```

3. And third question: this code looks very ugly, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: why do you want "to get rid of a bunch of empty strings ("") " while you have to count them in `spacing` param?

Comment: this issue shows that my regex is wrong somewhere

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to solve this problem with a lot of regexp when the first one you have is enough to solve this problem

So for the matches got for the regex `matches = line.match(re)`

- `matches[1]` represents the number of hyphens, therefore `separator = nHyphens.length`
- `matches[2]` is the hyperlink alt and for your case the `name`
- `matches[3]` is the hyperlink src which needs to be split by `/`, the two last items are `type` and `id`, *note that this assumes that the src will always have the same structure*

```js
function solve(content) {  
  const re = /(-+)\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^)"]+)\)/
  return content.split('\n').map(line => {
    // name,type,id,spacing
    let [full, hyp, alt, src] = line.match(re)
    src = src.split('/')
    return {
      name: alt,
      spacing: hyp.length,
      id: src[src.length - 1],
      type: src[src.length - 2]
    }
  })
}


const lines = `-[firstLink](https://webapp.com/topic/ab75ca14-dc7c-4c3f-9115-7b1b94f88ff6)
--[secondLink](https://webapp.com/source/d93f154c-fb1f-4967-a70d-7d120cacfb05)
-[thirdLink](https://webapp.com/topic/31b85921-c4af-48e5-81ae-7ce45f55df81)`

console.log(solve(lines))
```

Answer (score 1):

The needed array of objects can be obtained with few lines of code using `String.split`, `String.match` and `Array.map` functions(and I suppose, the following code doesn't look ugly at all):

```
const items = text.split(/\n/).map(function(v){
    var parts = v.match(/([-]+?)\[(\w+?)\]\(https?:\/\/[^/]+\/(\w+?)\/([^)]+)\b/);
    return {'name': parts[2], 'type': parts[3], 'id': parts[4], 'spacing': parts[1].length};
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(items, 0, 4));
```

The output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "firstLink",
        "type": "topic",
        "id": "ab75ca14-dc7c-4c3f-9115-7b1b94f88ff6",
        "spacing": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "secondLink",
        "type": "source",
        "id": "d93f154c-fb1f-4967-a70d-7d120cacfb05",
        "spacing": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "thirdLink",
        "type": "topic",
        "id": "31b85921-c4af-48e5-81ae-7ce45f55df81",
        "spacing": 1
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

And this would be my solution with `str.match()` without using any capture groups, `RegExp.exec()` method and `while` loops.

```js
var reg = /-+(?=\[)|[^[]+(?=])|[a-z]+(?=\/\w*-)|[\w-]+(?=\))/g,
   data = '-[firstLink](https://webapp.com/topic/ab75ca14-dc7c-4c3f-9115-7b1b94f88ff6)\n--[secondLink](https://webapp.com/source/d93f154c-fb1f-4967-a70d-7d120cacfb05)\n-[thirdLink](https://webapp.com/topic/31b85921-c4af-48e5-81ae-7ce45f55df81)',
    obj = data.match(reg).reduce((p,c,i) => (i%4 ? p[p.length-1].push(c) : p.push([c]) ,p),[])
                         .map(e => ({"name": e[1], "type": e[2], "id": e[3], "spacing": e[0].length}));
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
const array = text.split(/\n/);
let box, sliced;
const obj = array.map(line => {
    box = {};
    sliced = line.match(/\[[a-z]+\]/i)[0];
    box.name = sliced.slice(1, sliced.length - 1);
    box.spacing = line.match(/\-+/)[0].length;
    box.type = line.replace(/.*\.com\/([a-z]+)\/.*/, '$1');
    box.id = line.replace(/.*\/([a-z0-9\-]+)\)$/, '$1')
    return box;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's better to use `RegEx.exec`. Please try as my script.

```
const regex = /(-+)\[(\w+)\]\(([^)]+)\)/img;
const data = '-[firstLink](https://webapp.com/topic/ab75ca14-dc7c-4c3f-9115-7b1b94f88ff6)\n--[secondLink](https://webapp.com/source/d93f154c-fb1f-4967-a70d-7d120cacfb05)\n-[thirdLink](https://webapp.com/topic/31b85921-c4af-48e5-81ae-7ce45f55df81)';
var groups, items = [];
while(groups = regex.exec(data)){
    items.push({
        spacing: groups[1],
        name: groups[2],
        link: groups[3]
    })
}
```

If your links are always in the same domain, extracting type and id could be place in single regex.

```
const regex = /(-+)\[(\w+)\]\(https:\/\/webapp\.com\/(\w+)\/([^)]+)\)/img;
const data = '-[firstLink](https://webapp.com/topic/ab75ca14-dc7c-4c3f-9115-7b1b94f88ff6)\n--[secondLink](https://webapp.com/source/d93f154c-fb1f-4967-a70d-7d120cacfb05)\n-[thirdLink](https://webapp.com/topic/31b85921-c4af-48e5-81ae-7ce45f55df81)';
var groups, items = [];
while(groups = regex.exec(data)){
    items.push({
        spacing: groups[1].length,
        name: groups[2],
        type: groups[3],
        id: groups[4]
    })
}
```

Regarding your question on why your split result contains two additional empty strings, you should read section **Capturing parentheses** in [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split/)

Hope this will help.